# Google apps script can't be displayed properly for mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, viewport, meta-tags

I made some app for stock management and it works well.

Only problem is google script app can't be displayed properly for mobile and all texts shows too small.

[image]

I tried to apply directly viewport meta in my html header but failed.
I found lots of posts here for similar problem and tried some but still nothing works for mine.

Most posts like [My page doesn't scale in google app script. only on mobile and when not in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423742/my-page-doesnt-scale-in-google-app-script-only-on-mobile-and-when-not-in-lands) recommend using .addMetaTag in javascript code but
I got "TypeError: template.addMetaTag is not a function (line 31, file "Code")" error message

```
  doGet(request) {
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  return template
    //.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  
}
```

Please let me know what can I try more about this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: It isn't a method of a [template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template).  It's a method of [class HtmOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for help! var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Hello!').addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'); is works.

Comment: @Cooper So can't I refer my html file within meta tag?

Comment: I don't understand what your asking.  Please improve your [mcve]

Comment: For my webapps I have different css for different screen sizes.  For my own stuff I use the same one but develop it for my phone and just tolerate the weirdness on my laptop or desktop.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for advising. I solved problem with return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Cooper, I can solve the problem with .addMetaTag.

If you need to use javascript scriptlets, please refer code below

```
function doGet(request) {
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  var html = template.evaluate()
    .setTitle('Title');
  
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  htmlOutput.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  return htmlOutput;
}
```