# Google Apps Script - Mobile View - Screen is zoomed out too much

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

I've spent too long trying to figure out how to get my simple web app to not look so zoomed out on my Safari IOS app. It's like I'm looking at a website in desktop view.

The first thing that I find during research is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
But I'm almost 100% convinced it does nothing. Someone had the same issue, but they just removed the viewpoint tag, but still not fixing it.

I just want my html input tags, tables, and dropdown to maybe take the width of the screen.

I can't tell if bootstrap is the issue? Google Apps? My html table?

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Found out that i need to change my doGet function. [bottom answer helped me understand what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423742/my-page-doesnt-scale-in-google-app-script-only-on-mobile-and-when-not-in-lands)

```
function doGet(request) {
 var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index'); 
 var html = template.evaluate()
     .setTitle('Title');
 
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);   
 htmlOutput.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');   
 
 return htmlOutput
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I was trying to set the viewport tag within <head> tag of my html. It scaled in nicely but also stretched to the full width so I still had to scroll horizontally to see all items.